# SSHing between clients connected on OpenVPN

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services, openvpn

I have an AWS server hosting OpenVPN and two clients connected to the service. I have configured the OpenVPN server to allow inter-client communication and can see both clients connected to the service as well as confirm both clients having an active tunnel interface (both Linux clients) when connected.

Despite this the clients cannot communicate with one another. I have tried using netcat to open different ports from 22, 80, 8888 on TCP to test connectivity in between them along with ICMP requests but do not get anything back.

My goal is to have one client on the network act as an SSH server and the other client to connect to that SSH server both while being and tunneling traffic through the OpenVPN server.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Verify routing tables and firewalls, use tcpdump or similar to investigate traffic, maybe packets successfully flow in one direction but not the other.

Comment: Also, have you turned off the source/dest check on the EC2 instance acting as the OpenVPN server? And allowed packet forwarding at the OS/IPtables levels? If the server ends up acting as a router between the clients then it needs a few bits of config to work.